# how to disable a button by default and enable it when page load completely in asp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

If I am having a button in user control and by default I want to disable it and enable it when the page loads completely how can I achieve it in ASP.Net?

Can any help me with this the type of the button is button and it is in user control.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <button type="button" id="demo">
    Click me </button>
    <script>
    
     var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
     demo.disabled=true;
    
    
    window.onload = function(){
    demo.disabled=false;
    }
    
    
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using document.ready to know the page has loaded or not.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#demo").attr("disabled", false);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="demo" disable>
    Click me 
  </button>
```